# How to select records greater than max timestamp stored in a file from previous load from table in Pandas

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have SQL script from which I am extracting data storing into a data frame.

**Current Code**

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM ofs.ord_add oa
            WHERE
            oa.is_active = 'Y' AND   oa.or_ad_id = 5820  AND   oa.flag_value = 'Y'
    """)
    data3=cursor.fetchall()
    columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    order_addition = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=columns)
```

** Current Output- Run1**

```
ID     IS_ACTIVE   OR_AD_ID   FLAG_VALUE   INSERT TIMESTAMP
12300     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-06 08:12:53
14340     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-19 06:11:53
```

** Current Output-Run2**

```
ID     IS_ACTIVE   OR_AD_ID   FLAG_VALUE   INSERT TIMESTAMP
12300     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-06 08:12:53
14340     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-19 06:11:53
22368     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-22 08:12:53
34567     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-24 06:11:53
```

I am want use a condition in my current code such that :

1) max insert timestamp from the last run is stored in a file

2) In the next run of the SQL query, Only records greater than max timestamp stored in the file is 
   loaded into the dataframe.

**Expected Output after Run2**

```
  ID     IS_ACTIVE   OR_AD_ID   FLAG_VALUE   INSERT TIMESTAMP
  22368     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-22 08:12:53
  34567     Y          5820        Y         2020-01-24 06:11:53
```

How can this be done in python ?

Comment: Really good question. I have similar issue in my code as well.

Comment: do you mind showing an output of data3=cursor.fetchall()?

Comment: @sammywemmy, I have already posed, its same as  Output  posted above

Comment: How about storing the max_last_run in a database table where the query is fired. Then you could select all of the records > that value

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, I  would need to  handle that in linux server, so I would need to store the maximum timestamp from the previous run in  file

Comment: you may write the contents of the max_timestamp into a linux file as part of the program run. Then in the python code check for records > the max_timestamp value from the file

Comment: @sammywemmy, an idea on how to do this. I have already have outputs pasted in questions

Comment: create a variable unique_ids = tuple(dataframe.IDs.unique.tolist()), then run your sql query and add an extra where condition : AND oa.ID not in %s,' 
(unique_ids))    https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html. i post the link so you test more how to pass in external variables into your sql query (apologies if you already know how to do this).

Answer (score 0):

First, create a variable from the very first run:

```
unique_ids = tuple(dataframe.IDs.unique.tolist())
```

Then you execute the sql query the next time

```
cursor.execute("""
     SELECT * FROM ofs.ord_add oa
              WHERE
             oa.is_active = 'Y' AND   oa.or_ad_id = 5820  AND   oa.flag_value = 'Y'
             AND oa.ID NOT IN %(unique_ids)s; 
"""
({'unique_ids':unique_ids})
)
```

do test the variable place holding ... i may have bungled it in this code. But the whole idea is that before u run the query again, get the variable then pass it on to the query. https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html has a guide on how to pass variables in. love to get your feedback if it works or not